# Spring boot Kogito Mongodb integration

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, workflow, jbpm, kogito

I'm working on creating a kogito bpm spring boot project. I'm very happy to see reduced level of complexity on integration on jbpm in spring boot with the help of KOGITO. I'm struggling to find answers for my question, so posting them here,

- Kogito is a open source cloud offering for jbpm. I'm I correct?
- I see only mongodb or infinispan can only be used or supported with Kogito. I can't integrate psql with kogito. I'm I correct?
- I successfully created the spring boot kogito mongodb project and when I placed a .bpmn file in the resource folder, automatically endpoints got created. I was able to access, run the process and get response. But I don't see any entries created in MONGODB :| I don't even see the table being created. The .bpmn contains a simple hello world flow with start+scripttask+end nodes. Please explain help me understand this. Is the RuntimeMangar configured for per request stratergy? How can I change it?

Answer (score 1):

Answers inline.

> Kogito is a open source cloud offering for jbpm. I'm I correct?

Kogito is open-source and has jBPM integrated into its codebase to run on a cloud-native environment. In addition, a lot has been made to make it also run with native compilation if used with Quarkus.

> I see only mongodb or infinispan can only be used or supported with Kogito. I can't integrate psql with kogito. I'm I correct?

To this date, Kogito has the [following add-ons](https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-runtimes/tree/main/addons) to support persistence:

- Infinispan
- Postgres
- MongoDB
- JDBC (so you can extend to support any database you wish)

See more about it here https://docs.jboss.org/kogito/release/latest/html_single/#con-persistence_kogito-developing-process-services.

> But I don't see any entries created in MONGODB

Do you mind sharing a reproducer? Have you taken a look at the examples in https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples/tree/stable/process-mongodb-persistence-springboot? This example shows a call to a sub-process that relies on a user task. Hence the process must be persisted to fire up again on a new request to solve the task. However, since your process starts and ends in one request, there's nothing to be persisted in the DB:

> Runtime persistence is intended primarily for storing data that is required to resume workflow execution for a particular process instance. Persistence applies to both public and private processes that are not yet complete. Once a process completes, persistence is no longer applied. This persistence behavior means that only the information that is required to resume execution is persisted.

Comment: Is it possible to persist the audit/log data in the DB even after its completed the process?

Comment: Not at this moment.